# Mobile number validation on smart phone browser

Tags: javascript, validation, mobile

I used the below code to validate mobile number:

```
function lfnCheckMob(e) {
    var key1 = e.keyCode;
    if (key1 == 8 || key1 == 9 || key1 == 46 || (key1 >= 35 && key1 <= 40)) { return true; }
    if (e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    else {
        var key = e.keyCode;
        if (!((key >= 48 && key <= 57) || (key >= 96 && key <= 105))) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine on desktop browsers. But when I try it on a browser on smartphone, it allows special characters like &, @.
I tried putting alert to see the keycode value on phone, its showing keycode 0 for all the keys.
Can someone please help me for this?

Answer (score 0):

Either go with **1**

```
<input type="number" step="1" />
```

**OR**

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d*" />
```

And for more information, use [link](http://www.brucelawson.co.uk/2012/credit-card-bank-account-numbers-in-html5-forms/)

Comment: No, that did not help. And my bad, the link you provided is blocked in my company.